# Why do I need both a vimrc and a gvimrc?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

There seems to be two ways to store preferences specific to gvim:

1. Keep an `.vimrc` file for vim and a `.gvimrc` file for gvim specific additions.
2. Keep all settings in `.vimrc` and wrap gvim specific settings in a feature detection conditional:

   ```
   if has('gui_running')
       " gvim specific settings here
   endif
   ```

Given the existence of the latter option, why would I ever need a `.gvimrc` file?

Comment: One specific example which I find useful is `winpos` which changes the position of the window used by gvim. This has no effect (and makes no sense) within `~/.vimrc`, it has to be in `~/.gvimrc`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When the GUI starts, some settings are reset and then `.gvimrc` is processed.

Consequently, if you want a non-default value for any of those settings, you'll need to set it in a `.gvimrc`; testing for GUI mode in `.vimrc` won't work.

One such setting is `t_vb`, the terminal code used for the visual bell; in fact, all terminal optionals are reset to defaults for GUI mode (see `:help terminal-options`).

Additionally a bunch of GUI setup and menu customization is carried out; if you want to tweak any of that, you'll want that in a `.gvimrc` or it may not have any impact.

Reading over `:help gvimrc` provides a good overview of things that may change on you between the sourcing of your `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` that you may want to consider re-adjusting in the latter.

Comment: IIRC you can use the `:gui` command (within `has("gui_running")`, of course) to force the gui startup sequence to happen before any subsequent .vimrc commands. My .vimrc uses this to allow the default background light/dark setting to be set based on the actual GUI background color.